# How to get the label with the least sum distances if two of the classes are tie when classified with KNN only using python?

Tags: python, numpy, knn

Can really someone help me with this? I am building a KNN classifier from scratch and I wonder if one can get the class label with the smallest sum distances when two of the class labels are tied when classified. For example, if k=7 I get a NumPy array of the labels: [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2]. In these cases, the sum of labels is even, three 1s and three 0s. How can I get the least sum distances of these two classes to know which class label is the better picked? Any ideas? I have got up to here with no success!

```
def k_neighbours(X_, y_, x, k=7):
    lengths = [euclidean_length(x, x2) for x2 in X_]
    k_index = np.argsort(lengths)[: k]
    k_nearest_classes = [y_[i] for i in k_index]
    k_lengths = [lengths[i] for i in k_index]
    counts = np.bincount(k_nearest_classes)
    most_common_class = np.argmax(counts)
    for i in conuts:
        even_result[]
        get_numbers[]
        if i == sum(counts-1)/2:
            even_result.append(i)            
        elif len(even_result) == 2:
            get_numbers = [y_[i] for j in enumerate(k_nearest_classes)]                
                if j == 
                   sum(lengths[i])
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: `np.argpartition` is more suitable here than `argsort`. As for the question itself, create a 2d array with class, distance and a dummy variable for count. Group by classes and sum, then argmax by (count, distance). It would be even more concise with `pandas` for groupby

Comment: Thanks man! I will try that! Good stuff!

Comment: correction: argmax by `(count, -distance)` - distance should be negated to get the shorter sum first